# How to get array of values passed through .getJSON method in the controller method arguments

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have below jquery code,

```
 var ids = []
 var id ={"Param1": 1, "Param2": 2, "Param3": 3}
 ids.push(id)
 var id ={"Param1": 3, "Param2": 2, "Param3": 6}
 ids.push(id)

 $.getJSON("/Controller/Action1",
            {
                str: ids
            }
            , function (data) {
       });

  public JsonResult Action1(string[] str)
    {

        return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

I know string array is not correct. What is correct parameter type to get the collections passed from jQuery.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I tried List<string>, but values are null. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

For your Action try using FormCollection than look at the Key and Item collections

```
public JsonResult Action1(FormCollection ids)
{
      //ids["Param1.[0]"] <--Just off the top of my head, I think this is what the key name would be.
      //ids.AllKeys <--Use this to see the actual key names.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing array of an object, How can you parse it in a string.

Try this

Create class with same properties you want to pass.

```
public class Test
{
 public int Param1{get;set;}
 public int Param2{get;set;}
 public int Param3{get;set;}
}
```

Jquery

```
var Tests= []
 var Test={"Param1": 1, "Param2": 2, "Param3": 3}
 Tests.push(id)
 var Test={"Param1": 3, "Param2": 2, "Param3": 6}
 Tests.push(id)


$.getJSON("/Controller/Action1",
            {
                Tests: JSON.stringify(Tests)
            }
            , function (data) {
       });

  public JsonResult Action1(IList<Test> Tests)
    {

        return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to send collection of objects to controller, try following to achieve that :

```
 var data = {};
  data["ids[0].Param1"] = 1
  data["ids[0].Param2"] = 2
  data["ids[0].Param3"] = 3

  data["ids[1].Param1"] = 3
  data["ids[1].Param2"] = 2
  data["ids[1].Param3"] = 6

 $.getJSON("/Controller/Action1",data           
            , function (response) {
       });
```

then in your controller create a model so that you can bind to collection of that model :

```
public class MyModel
  {
    public int Param1{get;set;}
    public int Param2{get;set;}
    public int Param3{get;set;}
  }


    public JsonResult Action1(IList<MyModel> ids)
        {

            return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```